# How to Create a sub project folder to main project using Cmake

Tags: qt, cmake

I am very new to Ubuntu. There is big project file in Qt Ubuntu which has several folders for different individual projects. I need to add my project folder to that main folder using Cmake. I am unable to get perfect tutorials or guidelines to do it.As I found there three Cmake files for individual folders. 
Can anyone tell me how to create a new subproject in QT creator Ubuntu with Cmake using command promt.

Comment: You should ask platform-independent programming questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I am not going to move this (as was requested in flags) because this would more than likely be closed as "Unclear what you're asking" over on SO.

Comment: @ThomasWard And is it clear enough for AU? Or is it going to be closed?

Answer (score 0):

The command [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html) does exactly that.

```
add_subdirectory(<subfolder>)
```